# How to convert callback-based async function to async generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, asynccallback

It's currently possible to start asyncio servers by providing a callback that would fire on each incoming connection:

```
async def on_connection(reader, writer):
    # this is invoked each time a new connection is made
    pass

server = await asyncio.start_server(on_connection, host, port)
```

I would like to get rid of callback and use `async for` instead, so it would look like this:

```
async for reader, writer in my_start_server(host, port):
    # this should be invoked each time a new connection is made
    pass
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be very easy:

```
async def my_start_server(host, port):
    async def on_connection(reader, writer):
        # here I have to somehow yield (reader, writer) tuple
        # but if I do just `yield (reader, writer)`, it would 
        # make `on_connection` itself a generator, but would 
        # not affect `my_start_server`
        pass

    server = await asyncio.start_server(on_connection, host, port)
```

I have thought about having a class with `__aiter__` implementation there, but result seems to be overcomplicated a lot. So, is this the only way to go, or am I missing any easy approaches on converting async callbacks to async generators?

Comment: Usually, you want to be able to handle multiple clients at the same time. The `async for` approach doesn't allow that.

Comment: @Vincent, hm, you seem to be right - `async for` won't fetch next connection from the server until you have completed processing current one. I wish there was `async for` with "consume as soon as possible" semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vincent noticed, you shouldn't use `async for` to fetch connections since code inside it would block other connections from handling. Consider each connection as separate task that should be run regardless of others.

Here's example of how you can `yield` inside `my_start_server` using queue which also shows that we still will return to some sort of `on_connection`:

```
async def my_start_server(host, port):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def put(reader, writer):
        await queue.put((reader, writer,))

    await asyncio.start_server(put, host, port)

    while True:
        yield (await queue.get())
```

.

```
async for (reader, writer) in my_start_server(host, port):

    # If we will just handle reader/writer here, others will be suspended from handling.
    # We can avoid it starting some task,
    # but in this case 'handle' would be nothing different from 'on_connection'

    asyncio.Task(handle(reader, writer))
```