# Convert function using callbacks into Async Iterator variant

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynccallback, async-iterator

### Scenario

I'm given a function with an asynchronous callback like

```js
let readFile:   (path: string, callback: (line: string, eof: boolean) => void) => void
```

Though I would prefer a function using ***AsyncIterable***/***AsyncGenerator*** signature instead:

```js
let readFileV2: (path: string) => AsyncIterable<string>
```

### Problem

Without `readFileV2`, I have to read a file like

```js
let file = await new Promise((res, err) => {
    let file = ''
    readFile('./myfile.txt', (line, eof) => {
        if (eof) { return res(file) }
        file += line + '\n'
    })
})
```

.. while `readFileV2` allows me to do it cleaner like

```js
let file = '';
for await (let line of readFileV2('./myfile.txt')) {
    file += line + '\n'
}
```

### Question

<strike>Is there a way for me to transform `readFile` into `readFileV2`?</strike>

**Updated for clarification:**

Is there a *general approach* to transform a function with an async callback argument to an AsyncGenerator/AsyncIterable variant?

And can this approach be demonstrated on the `readFile` function above?

### References

I see two related questions here:

- [How to convert Node.js async streaming callback into an async generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862698/how-to-convert-node-js-async-streaming-callback-into-an-async-generator/60962966#60962966)
- [How to convert callback-based async function to async generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699067/how-to-convert-callback-based-async-function-to-async-generator)

However, they don't seem to provide a clear answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249277/discussion-on-question-by-mal-convert-function-using-callbacks-into-async-iterat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer at the outset: I am answering the following question:

> Given a data providing function `fn` of a form like `(...args: A, callback: (data: T, done: boolean) => void) => void` for some list of initial argument types `A` and data type `T`, how can we transform this function `transform(fn)` to produce a new function of the form `(...args: A) => AsyncIterable<T>`?

It is quite possible that this isn't the right thing to be doing in general, since consumers of `AsyncIterable<T>` may process data slowly or abort early, and a function of type `(...args: [...A, (data: T, done: boolean) => void]) => void` can't possibly react to that; it will call `callback` once per piece of data, whenever it wants, and it will not stop until it feels like it.

---

Still, here is one possible implementation:

```
const transform = <A extends any[], T>(
    fn: (...args: [...args: A, callback: (val: T, done: boolean) => void]) => void
) => (...args: A): AsyncIterable<T> => {
    let values: Promise<[T, boolean]>[] = [];
    let resolve: (x: [T, boolean]) => void;
    values.push(new Promise(r => { resolve = r; }));
    fn(...args, (val: T, done: boolean) => {
        resolve([val, done]);
        values.push(new Promise(r => { resolve = r; }));
    });
    return async function* () {
        let val: T;
        for (let i = 0, done = false; !done; i++) {
            [val, done] = await values[i];
            delete values[i];
            yield val;
        }
    }();
}
```

Essentially we provide a *queue* of data values, `values`, which gets written to  inside the callback passed to `fn`, and which gets read from inside a generator function.  This is accomplished by a chain of promises; the first promise is created manually, and each time data is available, it resolves the current promise and pushes new values with a new promise onto the queue.  The generator function awaits these promises, pulls data off the queue, and removes the consumed data.

---

To test it, someone needs to provide `fn`.  Here's one possibility:

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

const provideData = async (name: string, callback: (line: string, eof: boolean) => void) => {
    const contents = [
        "This is line 1 of " + name, "and this is line 2",
        "and line 3", "and 4", "5",
        "and that's the end of " + name + "."
    ];
    for (const [line, eof] of contents.map((l, i, a) => [l, i >= a.length - 1] as const)) {
        await sleep(1000); // I guess it takes a second to read each line
        callback(line, eof);
    }
}
```

The `provideData` function accepts a callback and calls it once per second with successive lines of an array.  And now we transform it:

```
const provideDataV2 = transform(provideData);
// let provideDataV2: (name: string) => AsyncIterable<string>
```

And let's test the transformer:

```
async function foo() {
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "starting")
    const iter = provideDataV2("my data");
    await sleep(2500); // not ready to read yet, I guess    
    for await (let line of iter) {
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), line)
    }
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "done")
}
foo()

/* 
[LOG]: "2:48:36 PM",  "starting" 
[LOG]: "2:48:37 PM",  "This is line 1 of my data" 
[LOG]: "2:48:38 PM",  "and this is line 2" 
[LOG]: "2:48:39 PM",  "and line 3" 
[LOG]: "2:48:40 PM",  "and 4" 
[LOG]: "2:48:41 PM",  "5" 
[LOG]: "2:48:42 PM",  "and that's the end of my data." 
[LOG]: "2:48:42 PM",  "done" 
*/
```

Looks good.

Is it perfect? Does it have weird side effects in response to weird situations (e.g., are you going to iterate it multiple times)? Should it handle errors in a particular way? Are there recommended solutions elsewhere? Not sure. This is just a possible implementation of `transform` that adheres to the contract laid out in the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAzE8C2MC8MA8AgjAKYAeUxYAJhDMgJ4DaAugDQwAqAfABQCwAKBjCYKMAC4YPAHSzE8AOYRJjWdPlLJBdsEQAbPQCNEwANaSeAN32SO7KuGKTDIEHuLIAlDi4xLIAEsqZm9sX38gwVDfGTlFZRgCTy0IejBgAEkKJEN3PG4fGABvQREYd1hrPQBXYgSABXgQDACIYjxGOxgXNw8wZi4WHBgWAG5SkQqYeDq3SycpUhUunvdkEMKIqnGhESraiGkAB2qIAAseMGIAdxhG5tbiHnhCounZvXnh+FGYAF9PJ4dmUxLF1PF2FYbJx7I5nK41mBosUJmVhDMIHMnowqrCriFgWjhPs6sdThcrrd7i02s9Xu9MZ9iN9fgCgaj-uzdujiFBqvAwHRUulRNV0lAAuAAFRSbwlbloqZVWyEoloF48KYBYYABjxzNwKH0bV+AEIHFdfgEANTWuUconCHH6fXMYaIa6IAKVfQHRgBZiqx3CKjECrMkkQf2Bh2O+gBMNUPz6INlP4cv48LnpgSCQSgSCwI5NSxBYgAEUQUEQ7uFwCkYEQGAW0HgATACh0+iMJnMUj07ZbCHbnZIIBQ8N6Xk2gSoyPlZQL0BgBYoYCgtFwjFjwgARBwzq0YEeB1cYABGGDjmC7mDWmCN5vsXfIJNQQ+0E+DmAAJl3rB3G9X3Kb8AGZ-yA6gYAAFgg3cAFZ-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-M8-wdgR+advXJbdgBOT292A97wMD4PdZdsPJZ1KPvZgrWg5153xeT6DL3qZWvYQzOE5z13JaywvTeAtCoEwuAzhwqCbaBkHqzI+Ps9Dg3oKrou92ZzOpTMgbRvFSVBT04gDJ4DAEjAaoMEMLrwbKGY+QFB9VupR48C2XgXjCVzeVp5jqigZ52HnwEdjigQgA)

Comment: You could go even further and use `Promise<IteratorResult<T>>` instead of a tuple, then just implement the iterator object yourself instead of using a generator function

Comment: @Bergi, is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3aGm) what you mean? Do you think that's an improvement or should I leave it alone?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot for your effort on this question and providing a solution. Just FYI I'm giving it a few more hours for edits/suggestions to tick in, and then I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

This has been a NodeJS-native API since v10, no need reinventing it:

```
const {createReadStream} = require('fs');
const {createInterface} = require('readline');

function readFileLines(fileName: string): AsyncIterable<string> {
    const input = createReadStream(fileName);
    return createInterface({input, crlfDelay: Infinity});
}
```

Testing it:

```
const lines = readFileLines('./test1.js');
for await(const l of lines) {
    console.log(l);
}
```

Comment: For clarity, the question in OP looks like "I'm given a function like `let readFile: (path: string, callback: (line: string, eof: boolean) => void) => void` though I would prefer a function like `let readFileV2: (path: string) => AsyncIterable<string>`. Is there a way for me to transform `readFile` into `readFileV2`?"  And your answer is something like "don't do that, whoever gave you `readFile` should take it back and give you a better function"? Are you saying this is an XY problem? Or am I missing something about how this answer addresses the question?

Comment: @jcalz There are many examples out there of how to take a function that can produce data step-by-step,  and then showing how to convert it into a generator. But the OP is giving a function example that shouldn't be wrapped into a generator, because it is producing all data at once, so any way you wrap it, you'll end up just doing more work, and quite inefficiently. That's why specifically for that `readFile` the best advice is not to do it, and resort to a more suitable file-read API that's available.

Comment: When you say "that `readFile`", what are you talking about? The toy implementation I put in [my playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOAyRm)?  Again, I am not the OP, I was just throwing together a mock/stub function to test against. Hopefully what you're saying is applicable to all possible implementations of `readFile` (such as [this](https://tsplay.dev/m36gyN)) and not just the particular ones I've been using as tests.

Comment: Also, since the question said "I'm given a function" and this answer is "don't use that, use `readFileLines` instead", I'm still a little concerned about whether it's possible for the OP to take such advice.  The OP presumably didn't *write* the function they are given, so they can't necessarily re-implement it... we don't know if the file system being probed is local, remote, virtual, etc, so I'd expect this answer to say something like "*if* the `readFile` function you are given is just reading from a local file system, you should throw it away and use the following instead:"

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for the contribution, and I'm sorry for not being clear in my original question. ***To clarify: I am seeking a general approach*** to the problem of converting an async callback function to an async iterator variant, and the supplied example code was just to serve as a platform to provide a solution. jcalz interpreted the question the way, I wanted it to in the first place

Comment: @Mal As I explained above, `readFile` makes a very poor example for a generic approach, because it is one function that should not be converted into a generator.

Comment: @vitaly-t I agree, and thanks for pointing it out. As mentioned in comments to the original question, my motivations stem from database stream handling

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I did this for [`Deno.serve`](https://deno.land/api@v1.30.0?unstable&s=Deno.serve) which is an HTTP server that takes a callback and an options object like `Deno.serve(req => respondWith(req), {port: 3000})`.

Basically the code is;

```
async function* emitterGen(opts){
  let _resolve,
      _req = new Promise((resolve,reject) => _resolve = resolve);
  Deno.serve( req => ( _resolve(req)
                     , _req = new Promise((resolve,reject) => _resolve = resolve)
                     )
            , opts
            );
  while (true){
    yield await _req;
  }
}

let reqEmitter = emitterGen({port: 3000});

for await (let req of reqEmitter){
  respondWith(req);
}
```

Obviously the code above is simplified, without exception handling. Yet it should be sufficient to answer your question.

Here is a working mock up sever which creates a random number (0-99) as request (`req`) at every random (0-999) `ms` and invokes `cb` (handler) with `req`. Stops after 5 iterations.

```js
function server(cb,ms){
  let count  = 5,
      looper = function(c = count,t = ms){
                 let stoid = setTimeout( req => ( cb(req)
                                                , --c && looper(c, Math.random()*1000 >>> 0)
                                                , clearTimeout(stoid)
                                                )
                                       , t
                                       , Math.random()*100 >>> 0
                                       )
               }
  looper();
}

async function* emitterGen(ms){
  let _resolve,
      _req = new Promise((resolve,reject) => _resolve = resolve);
  server( req => ( _resolve(req)
                 , _req = new Promise((resolve,reject) => _resolve = resolve)
                 )
        , ms
        );
  while (true){
    yield await _req;
  }
}

let reqEmitter = emitterGen(1000);

// since there is no top level await in SO snippets
(async function(){
  for await (let req of reqEmitter){
    console.log(`Received request is: ${req}`);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This solution *might* be risky, and certainly doesn't extrapolate.  Specifically: your resolve() handler must run immediately after the new request comes in, before any other new request is fired, or you will overwrite and drop entries.

Microtasks (resolve handlers) are guaranteed to run in the same task, so thats good, but if multiple new network requests could be emitted in the same task, that won't be good enough.  I don't know how Deno.serve is implemented maybe if guarantees a new task for each.

But for general solution, I think you would want an array of buffered values.

Comment: @mmocny Thanks for the comment. I can not see any reason to employ a buffer. Invoking the callback is invoking the `_resolve` with the received `req` and resolving yielded `_req` and resetting `_req` and `_resolve` with a new promise and it's `resolve` function to be used for the next `req` to be received. In fact we don't even need to use an async generator. We could drop the `async` keyword and use `yield _req;` istead of `yield await _req;` since `_req` is already a promise.

Comment: @mmocny OK I see your concern. This works with the assumtion of the consumer (the `for await of` loop) consumes the received requests faster than they arrive which might not be the case since we might need disk access or heavy processing to prepare a response and at the meantime another request may arrive. There can be two approaches. We may spawn a promisified thread and immediatelly return a promise that containes the eventual response. We may etablish an async queue which in fact [i had implemented previously](https://github.com/kedicesur/AQ) and easily applicable for this job.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class that can produce an async generator from any source:

```
/** Infinite async generator. Iterates messages pushed to it until closed. */
class Machina<T> {

  #open = true;
  #queue: T[] = [];
  #resolve: (() => void) | undefined;

  async * stream(): AsyncGenerator<T> {
    this.#open = true;

    while (this.#open) {
      if (this.#queue.length) {
        yield this.#queue.shift()!;
        continue;
      }

      await new Promise<void>((_resolve) => {
        this.#resolve = _resolve;
      });
    }
  }

  push(data: T): void {
    this.#queue.push(data);
    this.#resolve?.();
  }

  close(): void {
    this.#open = false;
    this.#resolve?.();
  }

}

export { Machina };
```

You can use it like this:

```
// Create the Machina instance
const machina = new Machina<string>();

// Async generator loop
async function getMessages() {
  for await (const msg of machina.stream()) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

// Start the generator
getMessages();

// Push messages to it
machina.push('hello!');
machina.push('whats up?');
machina.push('greetings');

// Stop the generator
machina.close();
```

For your specific case, something like this should work:

```
/** Read each line of the file as an AsyncGenerator. */
function readFileAsync(path: string): AsyncGenerator<string> {
  const machina = new Machina<string>();

  readFile(path, (line: string, eof: boolean) => {
    if (eof) {
      machina.close();
    } else {
      machina.push(line);
    }
  });

  return machina.stream();
}

// Usage
for await (const line of readFileAsync('file.txt')) {
  console.log(line);
}
```

### How it works

1. Calling `machina.stream()` kicks off an infinite loop, but it becomes paused immediately (on the first iteration) because it's waiting for a promise that isn't resolved.
2. Calling `machina.push()` adds an item to the buffer, and then unpauses it by resolving the promise. When it becomes unpaused, it empties the buffer into the stream and then pauses it again by awaiting a new promise.
3. The consumer of `machina.stream()` receives the pushed items. You can do this repeatedly.

Other considerations:

- Even if the Machina instance goes out of scope (ie ready to be garbage-collected), its promise will still run forever. So you need to manually call `machina.close()` when you are done streaming, if ever. Simply breaking out of the loop is not enough!
- I tried a slightly different design at first, without using a buffer. It turns out the buffer is needed, otherwise you cannot push multiple items in the same tick (all after the first will be dropped). But if you're only pushing one item per tick and are actively consuming the stream, the buffer will only ever contain one item. This is basically just a small memory consideration.